Kotlin data structure for efficient lookup of nested data
I am currently working on an application that needs to create a mapping between document pdfs and corresponding JSON data files. The files are coming from a third party so I have no control over their format. I am currently taking the incoming json files and deserializing them into kotlin data classes. The next step is to take the list of Idoc objects produced by the deserialization and convert them into a data structure that allows for easy lookup. Given a student id, document imageCode, and owner type (obtained from the filename of a pdf) I need to lookup the Document.documentYear value. What would be the most efficient way to do this?
My current thought is to simply create a Map. So given a
List<Idoc> idocs I would need to create a Map<Student.cbfId, Map<Document.imageCode, Map<DocumentOwner.type, Document>>> . I'm struggling to come up with a way to implement that however. I'm also not 100% sure that is actually the best approach.
Am I on the right track trying to structure the data as a nested Map or is there a better approach? If the map is the right way to go, how  do I actually implement that?
internal data class Idoc(@SerializedName("FileId") val fileId: String, @SerializedName("Student") val students: List<Student>)

internal data class Student(@SerializedName("Id") val id: String,
                            @SerializedName("SchoolId") val schoolId: String,
                            @SerializedName("Name") val name: String,
                            @SerializedName("Documents") val documents: List<Document>)

//Although owners is structured as a list, there will only ever be one Owner per Document      
internal data class Document(
    @SerializedName("Year") val documentYear: String,
    @SerializedName("Code") val imageCode: String,
    @SerializedName("DocumentOwner") val owners: List<DocumentOwner>,
)

internal data class DocumentOwner(@SerializedName("FirstName") val firstName: String,
                                  @SerializedName("LastName") val lastName: String,
                                  @SerializedName("OwnerType") val type: String


As an alternative, you can use Map<Triple<StudentId,ImageCode,OwnerType>, Document>.

That still leaves the problem of how to get from A to B. How do I take my list of nested data objects and turn them into a map with a triplet key?

Reflecting your nested structure, you can use a nested loop:

val map: Map<Triple<String, String, String>, Document> = buildMap {
    for (idoc in idocs)
        for (student in idocs.students)
            for (document in student.documents)
                for (owner in document.owners)
                    put(Triple(student.id, document.imageCode, owner.type), document)
}



While this brute force approach does technically get the job done, I am looking for something more efficient.
